# What is <ARRAY> string and how do I filter it?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Trying to query froma table in bigquery and filter using a column which is identified as TYPE: STRING, MODE: REPEATED.

When I try the following code:

```
select *
from transactions
where brands in (select brand from brand_list)
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot execute IN subquery with uncomparable types ARRAY<STRING> and STRING
```

Why does this happen and how can I filter a column that contains ARRAY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want something like this:

```sql
select *
from transactions
where exists (
  select 1 from brand_list, unnest(brands) as other_brand
  where brand = other_brand
)
```

This returns all rows where there is a brand in the array that also appears in the `brand_list` table.